# Router has no traffic-filter command. eNSP

Tags: networking, router, traffic-filtering

There was a problem. I built this diagram, indicated IP to each interface.

Topology

[image: Topology]

Created an access list. Added a rule to it. I went to the Ethernet 0/0/0 interface and tried to enter the traffic-filter command, but it was not there. I also tried to connect via Gigabit Ethernet, but this command just does not exist. I found a bunch of examples with this command on the Internet, but nothing worked for my router. I used the default router "Router". Please tell me what is my mistake?

[image: Error in console]

I need to use this command in the router to restrict forwarding traffic. But I do not have such a command, although I have seen many examples on the Internet using it.

P.s. translated with google translate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I am doing this in the eNSP program. I have a laboratory work and in it commands are entered in the same way in eNSP. I use a computer on a regular PC, a router is also a Router, a server is also a regular Server.

Comment: OK, that clarifed it. It's Huawei's Enterprise Network Simulator. I'd strongly recommend you ask the question in [Huawei forums](https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/index.html). This isn't a very well-known software. Stackexchange sites contain tens of millions of postings, and when I search for eNSP I find 4.